# Issue limiting decimal length

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

That the code I've used to limit to max 1 decimal number in all my `UITexField` :

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let computationString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)


    let arrayOfSubStrings = computationString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")


    if (arrayOfSubStrings.count == 1 && computationString.characters.count > 2) {

        return false

    } else if arrayOfSubStrings.count == 2 {
        let stringPostDecimal = arrayOfSubStrings[1]

        return stringPostDecimal.characters.count <= 1
    }



    return true
}
```

But I've just understand that there are two type of Decimal Pad: with dot and with comma.

For example my iOS Simulator use dot and my iPhone use comma.
So how can I fix that problem, stopping both of them?

Comment: Could you please let me know some sample numbers that you want to allow in your textfield?

Comment: I've wrote that. Max one decimal number, for example: 1.1 or 1,1 .

Comment: By the way, the simplest way to check validity of the string is using a regular expression. Note that even when keyboard contains only number keys, the user can still input other text for example using copy-paste. The regular expression pattern should be something similar to `^\d([.,]\d{1})?$`

Comment: I have disabled copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a method `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` to consider more than one separation character

```
let commaDotCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ",.")
let arrayOfSubStrings = computationString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(commaDotCharacterSet)
```

or to include also the decimal separator of the current locale

```
let localeDecimalSeparator = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleDecimalSeparator) as! String
let commaDotLocaleSeparatorCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ",." + localeDecimalSeparator)
let arrayOfSubStrings = computationString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(commaDotLocaleSeparatorCharacterSet)
```

Comment: In my experience, the best way is to use three characters - comma `,`, dot `.` and the `NSLocaleDecimalSeparator` from current locale.

Comment: Good point, I added this option to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let computationString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    let arrayOfSubStrings = computationString.computationString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ".,"))

    if (arrayOfSubStrings.count == 1 && computationString.characters.count > 2) {
        return false
    } else if arrayOfSubStrings.count == 2 {
        let stringPostDecimal = arrayOfSubStrings[1]
        return stringPostDecimal.characters.count <= 1
    }

    return true
}
```